# Flask-Sqlalchemy Model column always ordered, query takes too long, limit search

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

The problem is that query takes too long

I have model like a example:

```
class Stat(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'stat'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False, unique=True, autoincrement=True)
    object_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('object.id'))
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=False), server_default=utcnow(), nullable=False, index=True)
```

Date is always ordered.

Query I use

```
q = Stat.query.filter(id==Stat.object_id, dt>=Stat.date).order_by(Stat.id.desc()).first()
```

The problem is when some object stat is very old is looks for the result long time 1ms vs 10 seconds and at the point I dont care about the result because its older that set dt.

1. How can I change query that it would search for it LAST-TO-FIRST in the table perspective? Maybe order_by does id does it?
2. How can I change the Model/query that I would always know the date is ordered? So when it has gone past certain date, there cant be a result and I would get None
3. Query timeout? Dont want to solve it like that, but it would be a last option. But I believe that option dose not exist, there is only connection timeout

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: The speed should really be checked on the DB level. I think that you absolutely need an index on the `object_id` column. Depending on how many `Stat` entries you have per each `object_id`, a separate index covering both columns (`object_id, date` in this order) might be the best solution.

Comment: @jarlh - version? Flask-SQLachemy 3.0.3 and that uses SQLAlchemy 2.0.11

Comment: @van - I can try that, but was looking more of query base solution.

Comment: I understand. I think your query is good, but the execution is long because the database index you have (which I assume from `...index=True)` that you do) most likely is not used, and the full table scan is instead. You really should check the query execution to understand this. _You might try to remove the `, dt>=Stat.date` part from the query, but it is unlikely to help_.

Comment: "Which dbms are you using?" - They were asking about the actual database back-end you are querying. Is it PostgreSQL? MySQL? SQLite? …?

Comment: Engine is PostgreSQL